# Philiipine currency check to deposit in the US

Tags: united-states, banking, international-transfer, philippines, foreign-currency

We are expecting a check from a Home Builder in the Philippines in Philippine currency. Can we deposit it in our bank here in the US and convert to US currency ?

Comment: You should probably ask the bank?..

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on your bank. Some Banks would offer you the services, other would not. Please note it may take a month or tow for the credit to hit your account as the check has to physically be sent by your Bank to a Bank in Philippines and get it encashed.